# Outlook 2010: Your Outlook data file cannot be configured C:\Users\<username>.<domain>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\outlook2.ost?

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a user on a computer on our domain that we can't get Outlook to open her email because her roaming profile no longer exists in the location it did before...

Her user profile used to exist in `C:\users\<username>.<domain>` but now it exists in `C:\users\<username>` instead.

The original folder does not exist on the new machine.

When I try to load up outlook on her machine it complains that the file is missing with the error:

```
Your Outlook data file cannot be configured.
C:\Users\bmiller.ourdomain\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\outlook2.ost
```

How can I tell Outlook to look for her ost file in an existing directory?

Comment: What caused this profile change to begin with? It may be worth fixing that problem instead of chasing this one.

Comment: +1 For an issue I experienced just yesterday, which was caused by logging in onto another work station.

Comment: @r.tanner.f A failed hard drive with no backup.  We use roaming profiles.

Answer (score 3):

Reset it with the E-mail configurator.

You can find it in `Control panel > User Accounts > E-mail >`

- If the Outlook data file is synchronized with Exchange, then turn off 'cached modus' in the account settings, renew the Outlook profile, and turn 'cached modus' back on.
- If the Outlook data file is stand-alone, then update its location with the Data files option.

See also: [Error 0x8004010F in Outlook 2010](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2659085/en-us)

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that the path to the .ost file that Outlook is looking for exists and is writeable by the user. In my case I achieved this using `mklink /j` to make the profile visible under the previous path.